# Faster query plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server

simple question. I have a database and i'm trying to get all occurrences from a table in 3 rows.

```
RECEIPT | ORIGINAL_RECEIPT | EXCHANGED_RECEIPT

51651651 |     1245678      |   58453874
```

the query i'm using now works perfect and quite fast

```
select distinct RECEIPT from RECEIPT_DATA WHERE ORIGINAL_RECEIPT = '1245678'
UNION
select distinct ORIGINAL_RECEIPT from RECEIPT_DATA WHERE ORIGINAL_RECEIPT = '1245678'
UNION
select distinct EXCHANGED_RECEIPT from RECEIPT_DATA WHERE ORIGINAL_RECEIPT = '1245678'
order by RECEIPT asc
```

should then return

```
51651651
1245678 
58453874
```

obviously there is many more rows in mine and also the ORIGINAL_RECEIPT could have many exchanges and all.

Like I said this works perfect but I'm just curious what other ways are there going about it? Is there away to not search the database 3 times? 
I heard case could work with this? along with maybe a cross-apply?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: the 3 DISTINCT are not mandatory because you do UNION and not UNION ALL, so all duplicates will be removed. Doing the DISTINCTS adds suplementary steps for nothing.

Comment: Which one is it? MySQL or SQL Server? Make up your mind.

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL SERVER , and im using ms sql server management studio 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select DISTINCT (CASE WHEN n.n = 1 THEN RECEIPT
                      WHEN n.n = 2 THEN ORIGINAL_RECEIPT
                      WHEN n.n = 3 THEN EXCHANGED_RECEIPT
                 END
                )
from RECEIPT_DATA CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
WHERE ORIGINAL_RECEIPT  = '1245678';
```

And, you want an index on `RECEIPT_DATA(ORIGINAL_RECEIPT)`.

Your version of the query is doing lots of duplicate elimination -- both within each subquery and with the `UNION`.  This simplifies the duplicate elimination.

However, the biggest issue is probably the lack of index on `ORIGINAL_RECEIPT`.

This version will work in both MySQL and SQL Server.  However, in SQL Server, I would express it using `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying out your solution, looks very nice but I seem to be getting a syntax error just at the `) from RECEIPT_DATA CROSS JOIN/APPLY`
Just at the bracket, any ideas?

Comment: Found it, you just forgot to add the 'end' to the case when section! Maybe that's just for sql server? Thanks do its brilliant! :D edited above but can change it back if you wish

Answer (score 1):

You tagged SSMS so, i would use use `APPLY` instead of `UNION`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RDD.RECEIPTS
FROM RECEIPT_DATA RD CROSS APPLY 
     ( VALUES (RECEIPT), (ORIGINAL_RECEIPT), (EXCHANGED_RECEIPT) 
     ) RDD(RECEIPTS)
WHERE RD.ORIGINAL_RECEIPT = 1245678;
```

`DISTINCT` is really unnecessary since you used `UNION`, so it will remove duplicates for you.

However, for better performance you will need an index on `RECEIPT_DATA(ORIGINAL_RECEIPT)`.